# How to use python diff_match_patch to create a patch and apply it

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, match, diff

I'm looking for a pythonic way to compare two files file1 and file2 obtain the differences in form of a patch file and merge their differences into file2. The code should do something like this:

```
diff file1 file2 > diff.patch
apply the patch diff.patch to file2 // this must be doing something like git apply.
```

I have seen the following post [Implementing Google's DiffMatchPatch API for Python 2/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075864/implementing-googles-diffmatchpatch-api-for-python-2-3) on google's python API dif_match_patch to find the differences but I'm looking for a solution to create and apply patch.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to install `diff_match_patch`.

Here is my code:

```js
import sys
import time
import diff_match_patch as dmp_module


def readFileToText(filePath):
 file = open(filePath,"r")
 s = ''
 for line in file:
      s = s + line
 return s
    

dmp = dmp_module.diff_match_patch()
origin = sys.argv[1];
lastest = sys.argv[2];

originText = readFileToText(origin)
lastestText = readFileToText(lastest)

patch = dmp.patch_make(originText, lastestText)
patchText = dmp.patch_toText(patch)

# floder = sys.argv[1]
floder = '/Users/test/Documents/patch'
print(floder)
patchFilePath = floder
patchFile = open(patchFilePath,"w")
patchFile.write(patchText)

print(patchText)
```